# communication foundation showing plain text / code behind

Tags: c#, wcf

i have a wcf service which runs perfectly on my dev machine (vs2010, target 3.5) but once deployed, it shows me the code behind of the service (actually the plain text of the .svc file) and not the normal service page:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="SilverlightPoc.Web.FinanceData" CodeBehind="FinanceData.svc.cs" %>
```

Anyone any idea why the .svc file is rendered as plain text and not as wcf service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.svc` extension is probably not associated with the `aspnet_isapi.dll` filter (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll):

[alt text http://www.chitech.net/blog/SilverSample1.3/Figure2.jpg](http://www.chitech.net/blog/SilverSample1.3/Figure2.jpg)

Comment: And maybe run the ASPNET_REGIIS tool (cmd line).